# Focus Ring on jQuery UI Dialog Button

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've got a jQuery dialog box with a button to close it. The button has focus when the dialog box opens. The problem is that the focus is a dotted line around the button's text instead of a focus ring around the entire button. I'm using jQuery's smoothness theme.

I'm using the dialog in a WordPress plugin.

My code is:

```
$('#mydialog').dialog({
        title: 'My Title',
        position: [619,200],
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {"OK" : function(){$(this).dialog("close");}}
    });
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what browser are you using?

Comment: @WilliamNiu, You're right. Firefox's default focus is the dotted line. It looks fine in other browsers. If you switch you comment to an answer, I'll give you the green check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may relate to the browser; the way each browser highlights the focused element differs.